# Can't import from custom path with tsconfig-paths

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm staring from an example project,

```
npx degit reduxjs/redux-templates/packages/vite-template-redux my-app
```

Installed [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) with yarn

```
yarn add tsconfig-paths
```

I've added a few lines in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And created src/work.tsx

```
export default function qwe() {
    return '123'
}
```

Howerver, `import qwe from "~/work"` does not work

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "~/work" from "src/App.tsx". Does the file exist?
```

What was wrong?

**EDIT**

This project has a [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/outline/outline/blob/main/tsconfig.json#L30)

```
    "paths": {
      "prosemirror-markdown": ["./node_modules/@types/prosemirror-markdown"],
      "@server/*": ["./server/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["./shared/*"],
      "~/*": ["./app/*"]
    }
```

And the frontend part supports [importing from ~/xxx](https://github.com/outline/outline/blob/main/app/scenes/Archive.tsx#L9)

```
import Scene from "~/components/Scene";
import Subheading from "~/components/Subheading";
import useStores from "~/hooks/useStores";
```

How does this project work?

Comment: Are you sure that's a TS node project? That's what the plugin is for. There's a webpack version  of the plugin and TS loader has some support built in but I don't think the plug in you're using is meant to work with client side apps

Comment: @AluanHaddad I found another project that can do the job, but it didn't use the plugin I mentioned, edited question

Comment: That configuration looks correct, but I still don't understand the question. Are you asking how that can work or how that can be made to work?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, I want to use the `~/xxx` path as well, but it didn't work somehow

Comment: I'm not familiar with that tool but the documentation for the template that generated the app suggests that you need to configure vite to understand the path mapping. Check out the docs https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ah, this worked for me. And it exists in the outline project as well, nicely done!